# Javascript/JQuery - Option selected from Select Field - best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form I've got a select field;

```
        <select id="setColor">
            <option value="black">black</option>
            <option value="white">white</option>
            <option value="both">both</option>
        </select>
```

And whenever each option is selected I want a different thing to happen;

```
    <script>
        var setColor = function(){

            var selectVal = $("#setColor").val();

            if(selectVal === "black"){
                //do something when "black" is selected
            }
            else if(selectVal === "white"){
                //do something when "white" is selected
            }
            else {
                //do something when "both" is selected
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(setColor());

    </script>
```

This has already been answered in [Execute script based on which option is selected in a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071992/execute-script-based-on-which-option-is-selected-in-a-select-box), but the problem is, whenever more options get added (eg. colours), I'll have to add in more code in the JS. So the question is, is there a better way of writing the JS/Jquery to prevent me from having to add more code whenever an option gets added.

Comment: Well, you have to add *something* if you add a new option, if you want to do something different for that option. You could make this easier by using a `option => function` map.

Comment: you need to look at [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change) handler

Comment: The best option would be that when you add your new options to the select you also define your event handler reaction at the same time like a custom callback function